# 11.1v to 12v vs 14.8v to 12v

Tags: batteries

I need to get either a 11.1v battery to 12v or 14.8v battery to 12v for a camera. The current draw will be less than 250mah. I was wondering what the cheapest and easiest way to do that is. I will be using either of my two lipo batteries for my power source. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I presume by 11.1V you are referring to a 3S LiIon or LiPo cell. In which case the terminal voltage when charged is 12.6V. You don't say what camera you are using. Also "mAh" is a unit of charge, not current.

Comment: The camera is an old security camera. There is hardly any documentation on it but it still works. Sorry if I'm naming these things wrong. I am completely self taught so I don't always call things by there right name. I guess it would be .25 amps or 25 mA.

Comment: In addition to the voltage range, it will be very hard to safely configure a lithium battery to be maintained in charge while in use.  Unless the device requires light weight portability you may want to look at more traditional solutions such as gel cells as typically used by wall mounted emergency lights, computer UPS's, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware that a nominal 11.1v battery is 3 LiPo cells, or 3S, which could range from as low as 8.1v to as high as 12.6v. Similary the 4S battery could cover 10.8v to 16.8v. However, you don't need to use all of the range, at the cost of capacity. A standard charger will always tend to give you the top of the voltage range, but you can curtail the use before it drops to the bottom of the range.

As the 3S would need both buck and boost to cover your 12v requirement, it's probably easier to use buck only from your 4S battery, and not use the bottom part of the range.

Ideally you'd use a 2S or a 5S, and then the whole discharge voltage range will be covered with a single boost or buck converter respectively.

Comment: So if I was to use a 5S then I would I would need a buck converter? Could you give me an example of one? Thanks for your help.

Comment: something like this perhaps? http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Adjustable-3A-Mini-4-5V-28V-to-0-8V-20V-DC-DC-Step-Down-Converter-Power-Supply-/112250326590?hash=item1a22a40e3e:g:cDwAAOSwMmBVmGbJ

Answer (score 2):

In practice a 3S lipo is almost flat at 11.1V, and your '12V' camera probably regulates down to a lower voltage internally. I would try an 11.1V battery and see what happens. If your camera continues to work down to 11V then it should be fine.

Also make sure that the battery cannot get over-discharged! Do not let it go below 10.5V for 3S or 14V for 4S.